# Display inline-block generates a margin-bottom that i can't remove

Tags: css, margin, padding

I tried every combination of display, float, width/height and set all the margins and paddings to 0 but having the container with display: inline-block always generates a margin-bottom that I can only remove by adding the style "margin-bottom: - ... px "

Please take a look at the code, it's very basic [index.php](http://echidnavideos.altervista.org/wp-content/themes/Kent/admin/edit-posts.php)

Anyway I'm open to any kind of solution, I just want the div ".posts" to contain the posts so if there are solutions without "display: inline-block" it's okay to me.

Thanks everybody in advance

Comment: what space.? spaces just after blue blocks.?

Comment: Why does it need to be inline-block in the first place? Why not block? (Or nothing, since div is a block element by default)

Comment: Anyway since inline-block makes the element inline, it gets extra height from line-height. If you set its parent's (in this case `#main`) line-height to 0 you won't have the space. You might have to set a different line height for inner elements though to undo this for your actual text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space you are seeing is the space given to the [descender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender) height of letters like a lowercase **y** or **g** when an element's display value is set to `inline-block;`. You are essentially treating an element like it is text when you set it to `display: inline-block;`.

To fix, remove `display: inline-block;` from your `.posts` DIV. It doesn't need it for the layout you have.

Comment: I didn't know that space was due to the descender! Always thought inline elements were just being annoying. Thanks for that!

Comment: If you do a search for `space under img tag`. That space is due to an `<img>` tag being `inline-block` by default and providing room for the descender. [SO post illustrating the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917008/space-under-img-tag).

Comment: I've fixed this problem before by setting `display: block` on images, but again thought it was just some weird line-height quirk. Notice the word "descender" isn't actually mentioned in the link you provided :)   (I'm not the OP btw, in case you missed that)

Comment: @TalyaS true, and I noticed. The link does visually show the space between the bottom of the image and the border being applied to the outer DIV as an example of `inline-block`. The gap is that descender space. My answer is just one solution. The one given in the link is another. [Here's a post that does mention _"descender"_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774814/remove-white-space-below-image).

Comment: Sure, I was just grateful that you gave me a name (and an explanation) for the phenomenon. I wasn't criticizing the link you provided- I was pointing out that they didn't know what it was either. They gave solutions- but like me they thought it was a quirk. Edit: noticed the new link you provided now, cool. Learned something new today anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Figured I might as well post this as an answer:

I don't see why it needs to be `inline-block` in the first place and not a regular `block`, but in case it does- since `inline-block` makes the element inline, it gets extra height from <s>line-height</s> the [descender](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32787661/5297207). If you set its parent's (in this case `#main`'s) `line-height: 0` you won't have the extra space.

You'll have to make up for this later by giving your inner elements a different `line-height`, like `.posts { line-height:1.5 }` or your text won't have any height.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're using #post in several places. This is very bad practice. Using ID's should be unique. You're going to get really mixed CSS output as a result of that. Change those to .post. See https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Secondly, .posts should be `display: block`, since you're not lining them up in a row. See: http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/

Thirdly, your .sep has `margin: 8px 33px`, which is creating the space. If you remove that margin, you won't have that space.

Comment: `.sep` is not creating the space between `.posts` and `.footer`. Remove the `.sep` class in Dev Tools and you will see. Please see my answer as to why.

Comment: Good observation. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

you can add `font-size:0` property to the class posts and change its value in post class according to your requirment

Comment: Yeah I see that by setting font-size or line-height to 0 it works even with display:inline-block. Thanks a lot!